# Can I do an interactive :substitute (search & replace)?

Tags: substitute

Sometimes I use `:s` with a complicated regexp which may or may not be correct, or I'm not sure if I want to replace *all* matches.

Is there any way I can tell Vim to confirm every match it finds before it actually replaces the text?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes! Use the `c` flag for `:substitute`. From `:help substitute`:

```
[c]     Confirm each substitution.  Vim highlights the matching string (with
        hl-IncSearch).  You can type:                           :s_c
            'y'     to substitute this match
            'l'     to substitute this match and then quit ("last")
            'n'     to skip this match
            <Esc>   to quit substituting
            'a'     to substitute this and all remaining matches {not in Vi}
            'q'     to quit substituting {not in Vi}
            CTRL-E  to scroll the screen up {not in Vi, not available when
                        compiled without the +insert_expand feature}
            CTRL-Y  to scroll the screen down {not in Vi, not available when
                        compiled without the +insert_expand feature}
```

Example usage is simple as pie:

```
%s/old/new/gc
```

This is very useful, but didn't know about this until 2 weeks ago :-) And it's even available in ol' vi :-)

Bonus tip: You may also want to use `:set nowrapscan`; this prevents Vim from wrapping to top when it hits the bottom. I've found this to be *especially useful* when using the `c` flag.

Comment: I would also add that if you want to replace all instances of `old` in the same line (not just the first occurrence) you should add `g` at the end of the command so in total you will have `%s/old/new/gc`

Comment: Oh, yeah; I have `set gdefault` so I tend to forgot to add it in examples @e271p314 

Answer (score 23):

In addition to what Carpetsmoker said:

The `&incsearch` (`set incsearch`) setting in Vim is really useful. You can use it together with a useful and little known trick.

The trick is to try out your complex regex by just using the `/` or `?` command. Vim will use the `&incsearch` setting to show matches interactively. Once you're happy with the regex, you can use `:%s//replacement` to have vim use the previous search.

Notice how the part in `//` is blank (that's where you put the text to search). If you leave it blank, you are telling Vim to use the previous search regex. With this, you can type out a complex regex with `/` and have all the benefits of `set incsearch`, and then use the `%s//replacement` command to actually execute the search and replace.

If you want something similar to incsearch for `:s` commands, check out [vim-over](https://github.com/osyo-manga/vim-over), but I just prefer using the native Vim way.

Comment: I used to use a variant of this: Just use `:%s/pattern/replace/` and then press `u` for undo, you can see the parts that Vim changed if you have `hlsearch` enabled. And you can replace this text again with `^R`.

Answer (score 14):

My favorite interactive substitution is to **search** using <kbd>/</kbd> and go through the matches using <kbd>n</kbd>.

Then **select** match using <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> and then <kbd>s</kbd> to **substitute** the text with whatever I like.

And **repeat** by moving to next match and pressing <kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: This is a very nice trick, because it is: (1) interactive, (2) you can go previous match if you accidentally skipped it (something that you cannot do using `:s/old/new/gc`).

Answer (score 5):

In Neovim there also is the [`'inccommand'`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27inccommand%27) option which lets you preview the result of the `:s` command while you type it.

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of everyone, `incsearch` was updated in vim8 to also show preview as you type the pattern