# Pass word one-by-one and replace (Search and replace with confirmation)

Tags: command-line, search, replace

I'd like to pass through a text an replace `word1` by `word2`. However, I don't want to execute this task in one pass, but rather word by word. I know I could put the cursor on the word I want, execute `*`, then `vw` and finally `r words`. The problem is located on this last step. If I want to look for the next `words`, I can't with `*`, because I'd replace `word1` by `word2`. Could anyone be able to help me at this point?

Comment: Alternatively in the workflow you've described you can just press `n` as `word1` is still in the search register and `n` will take you to the next occurrence.

Comment: Also: [Can I do an interactive :substitute (search & replace)?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/373/51).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for the substitute command with confirmation:

```
:%s/word1/word2/gc
```

This will substitute `word2` for `word1`, but every time it will take you to the match and let you decide what to do.

- `g` means global. It will find all matches on the line.
- `c` is for confirm. It applies the behavior described above.

See [`:help :substitute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Asubstitute) and [`:help :s_c`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3As_c) for more info.